Rebuild a Maven project from its artifact
I was asked by my customer to rebuild a Maven project (Java files, css, js, pom.xml) from its artifact afterwork-1.1.ear. It has the following structure inside:
afterworkWeb-1.1.war
META-INF/

I decompressed afterworkWeb-1.1.war and, in the end, this is the full path structure (includes both META-INF/ and aftweworkWeb-1.1/ expanded):
afterwork-1.1/
├── afterworkWeb-1.1/
│   ├── include/
│   ├── css/
│   ├── docs/
│   ├── images/
│   ├── js/
│   ├── META-INF/
│   │   ├── maven/
│   │   │   └── com.workplace.afterwork/
│   │   │       └── afterworkWeb/
│   │   │           ├── pom.properties
│   │   │           └── pom.xml
│   │   ├── context.xml
│   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── WEB-INF/
│       ├── classes/
│       │   ├── com/
│       │   │   └── workplace/
│       │   │       └── afterwork/
│       │   │           ├── action/
│       │   │           │   └── *.class
│       │   │           ├── dao/
│       │   │           │   └── *.class
│       │   │           └── ...
│       │   └── log4j.properties
│       ├── lib/
│       │   └── *.jar
│       ├── pom-lib/
│       │   ├── javax.servlet.jar
│       │   └── javax.servlet.jsp.jar
│       └── *.jsp      
└── META-INF/
    ├── maven/
    │   └── com.workplace.afterwork/
    │       └── afterworkEar/
    │           ├── pom.properties
    │           └── pom.xml
    ├── application.xml
    └── MANIFEST.MF  

The following is the pom.xml in the path aftwework-1.1/afterworkWeb-1.1/META-INF/maven/com.workplace.afterwork/afterWorkWeb
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.workplace.afterworkWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>afterworkWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>1.1</version>
    <name>afterworkWeb</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.workplace.afterworkWeb</groupId>
        <artifactId>afterworkSuperpom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.officefloor.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>officeplugin_war</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collection</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collection</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax-servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/pom-lib/javax.servlet.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax-servlet-jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax-servlet-jsp</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/pom-lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts-core</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts-el</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-el</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts-el-1.3.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts-extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts-extras-1.3.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts-mailreader-dao</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-mailreader-dao</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts-mailreader-dao-1.3.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts-scripting</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-scripting</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts-scripting-1.3.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts-taglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts-tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jxl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jxl.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>${basedir}/target</targetPath>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <directory>${basedir}/WebContent</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warName>afterworkWeb</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <includes>
                        <include>src/**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>${basedir}/target/classes/</targetPath>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>

the following is the pom.xml in the path afterwork-1.1/META-INF/maven/com.workplace.afterwork/afterworkEar
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>com.workplace.afterworkWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>afterworkEar</artifactId>
    <name>afterworkEar</name>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <description>afterworkEar</description>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.workplace.afterworkWeb</groupId>
        <artifactId>afterworkSuperpom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </parent>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <type>war</type>
            <groupId>com.workplace.afterworkWeb</groupId>
            <artifactId>afterworkWeb</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <version>1.4</version>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.workplace.afterworkWeb</groupId>
                            <artifactId>afterworkWeb</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>studio</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins> 
    </build> 

</project>

I made an empty project afterwork with the following structure inside:
afterwork/
├── pom.xml
└── afterworkWeb/
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src/
        └── main/
            ├── java/
            │   └── com/
            │       └── workplace/
            │           └── afterwork/
            │               ├── action/
            │               │   └── *.java
            │               ├── dao/
            │               │   └── *.java
            │               └── .../
            │                   └── *.java 
            ├── resources/
            │   └── log4j.properties
            └── webapp/
                ├── include/
                ├── css/
                ├── docs/
                ├── images/
                ├── js/
                ├── META-INF/
                │   ├── context.xml
                │   └── MANIFEST.MF
                └── WEB-INF/
                    ├── lib/
                    │   └── *.jar
                    ├── pom-lib/
                    │   ├── javax.servlet.jar
                    │   └── javax.servlet.jsp.jar   
                    ├── struts-config.xml
                    ├── web.xml
                    └── *.jsp

where afterwork/pom.xml is the same pom.xml under afterwork-1.1/META-INF/maven/com.workplace.afterwork/afterworkEar  and afterwork/afterworkWeb/pom.xml is the same pom.xml under afterworkWeb-1.1/META-INF/maven/com.workplace.afterwork/afterWorkWeb.
All of the .java files are obtained by using jd-gui tool to decompile .class.
If I go to afterwork directory and launch the following command (Java 6 requires maven 3.0.5)
mvn clear package

I get the following output
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.workplace.afterworkWeb:afterworkEar:1.1 (C:\WORKDIR\PROJECTS\DEVELOPMENT\afterwork\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.workplace.afterworkWeb:afterworkSuperpom:pom:1.1 in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central-no-ssl has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 12 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

I thank in advance to whomever could give me helpful hints and suggestion

maven build files (pom.xml) are a hierarchy, just like java classes. Even if you write class Foo {}, then that's just shorthand for class Foo extends Object {}, and the definition of Foo starts with everything Object has, and then Foo extends functionality (adds new methods/fields) or overwrites functionality (overrides methods defined in Object).
POMs are the same. All POMs have a parent whether you mention one or not, and the POM file is considered to 'expand and adjust' the parent, resulting in a single entity ('merging' the parent and this pom.xml) which is then executed.
java ships with java.lang.Object; you do not write it yourself. Similarly, maven ships with the default parent. But, the pom listed here explicitly defines a parent - the equivalent of extends SomeSuperType, and, crucially, that parent is nowhere in the war file in any way.
For that matter, neither are the source files. Nevertheless from your question it sounds like you found the source files someplace and not in that war file (if you do not have the source files, this is a muuuuch simpler answer. Namely: "Tough break there. What you want is not possible. Go tell whomever asked you to do this to find another solution, you can't reconstruct the build from the war file")... so where-ever you got those java files from, try to get the super pom from there. It will be the pom file from the project named 'afterworkSuperpom'.
This section of the pom file defines the parent:
<parent>
        <groupId>com.workplace.afterworkWeb</groupId>
        <artifactId>afterworkSuperpom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
</parent>

I don't have that superpom
Then you cannot recreate the build. Period.
However, if you want to merely get as close as possible, knowing that it's not the same, and knowing that perhaps that superpom is crucial (i.e. what you're really doing is creating a platform from which you can start, indiana jones style, reconstructing what that superpom most have done, one tedious step at a time; this will be a ton of work and require lots of experience in the worst case. It's not possible to predict what that superpom was setting up; maybe it contained 95% of the trickiness in this build, who knows?) -... simply remove that section of the pom and try to build it.

Thank you for your answer! I now the hierarchy of pom.xml and their pom parent. As I wrote, I got the the source files using jd-gui. In the war there where only .class files.
Regarding superpom, I know that is missing but, from the pom children, I don't know if I should put two modules, afterworkWeb and afterworkEar alongside pom.xml (which is the superpom) at the same level under the afterwork directory and creating the superpom only including the two modules inside it: if so, should afterworkEar only include its pom.xml or what else, and what? I'm confused!
